# Can Hidden element be accessed by javascript getElementByName?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have Hidden field 
like

```
<%= Html.Hidden("ID", 1) %>
```

and in javascript i want a value of that field by

```
var ID = document.getElementsByName("ID").value;
```

I can't access it!

is there any other way?

Comment: Which browser? It works fine for me in FireFox.

Comment: That should work, which browser are you using? perhaps IE doesnt like names of "ID" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of the context but shouldn't you be using [getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp) ??

Comment: Actually, since the post is tagged with ASP.NET MVC, he should be using jQuery (since it's included with the template).   $('#ID') works nicely.

Comment: Fair enough, didn't notice the tag! I was referring to the use of ByName instead of ById, which is what I thought was causing it to not work.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
<input type="hidden" id="ID" />
```

for javascript to access it :

```
var ID = document.getElementById("ID").value;
```

other way with JQuery :

```
var ID = $('#ID').val();
```

Comment: I especially like this answer for including jQuery because the question was tagged with MVC.  Someone using MVC really ought to be using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you want to be doing is:

```
var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

id do this:

```
<% Html.Hidden("ID", 1, new { id = "MyHidden"}) %>

document.getElementById("MyHidden").value
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `getElementsByName(name)` returns an array of elements with the given name property.
2. `getElementById(id)` returns the element with the given id property.
3. There is no getElementsById - because two elements with same id is not allowed.
4. Nor are getElementsByID, getElementByID - these aren't existing javascript functions. Camelization is required!

Answering the question:

You can get the id of a hidden element if it is hidden client side. (You can see it in the generated source.)

```
document.getElementById('ID').value;
```

Or something like this.